# Java generics excercise - answer explanation

Tags: java, generics

In the official Java documentation there are some exercises with answers at the end of the generics chapter. I was able to solve most, however one answer is not clear to me. You can find the questions and answers [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/QandE/generics-answers.html). I don't understand the answer on question 8. Why do they write

```
<T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>
```

I did write

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

and don't see why extends Object is necessary or better.

Comment: There is more discussion of this "trick" here: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ104

Comment: Thanks for your comments, they were very helpful! As I understand it, the Object extension is not necessary and only inserted for not to break the legacy api, which is more or less a bug. So it would be totally fine (or even better) to do it in the way I did...

Comment: @user1361466 that is the way that I think of it yes, although it is perhaps less of a bug and more of a feature ;)   When adding Generics, the language designers were determined to maintain backwards compatibility with previous releases of Java, and as such (rightly or wrongly) they made many compromises with Generics.

Comment: @ChrisK I meant that it was a Bug to define Object as the return Type of max and not Comparable.

Answer (score 1):

I had to think twice about that one. Here is why:

If you wrote

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

it would mean that your `T` has to **extend** `Comparable`. What you want is for it to **implement** `Comparable`.

In order to do so, you have to make it extend a class and then precise what interfaces must be implemented.

As you don't need any special class, you must then extend `Object`, once it's done, you can precise what interface to implement.

Syntax:

```
<T extends ClassToExtend & InterfaceToImplement>
```

Comment: If I omit the Object extension then T does not need to be an interface, as I understand it, but a Type. As the comment above suggests, the problem seems to be to be compatible with legacy code which requires the return type to be Object but here we get, after Type erasure, Comparable.

Comment: Not quite. For `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`, `T` can be *any* type, interface or class, that is or extends `Comparable`.

Comment: OK, I didn't know a class could extend an interface... Il update my answer.